# Unable to connect Bluetooth device 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

As the title suggests I cannot connect to any Bluetooth devices, particularly my Airpods.
I can scan for devices and the name 'Airpods' shows up, however, once I click on the 'Set up' button the system hangs for a bit and never connects to the device. I even tried installing blueman but I am unable to find where the executable file is to run the program.

Comment: What is the command you used ti install Blueman? Have you tied the search your computer icon, it is usually the top icon in the dock.

Comment: So, it turns out there was an icon at the top left of the screen, however, the problem is I still cannot pair my device. Is there any commands I can use to diagnose the problem?